# How to check for start of line using Ant replaceregexp task

Tags: regex, ant

I have a file where I want to replace the old value with a new value. Inside my file I have the following contents:

I want to replace myList value with some other value. For that I used the "replaceregexp" task in Ant. I have used the following code for that and this will check for commented myList also.

```
//myList="a","b","c","d","e";
myList="a","b","c","d","e";

<replaceregexp file="myfilename" match="myList=(.*)" replace="myList="somevalue" />
```

I want to know how can I check for start of the line. Which means it has to replace only if the line starts with "myList" and not if a line starts with "//myList".

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need to keep the commented line? I suggest just using Ant's `propertyfile` task to change property values. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html

Comment: It is a groovy file for which i need to modify. Instead of parsing the complete file and to proceed, I have used replaceregexp.

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic regular expression question.  There are a few ways to do it, most commonly you would use the caret (`^`) character to mark the start of a line, like:

```
<replaceregexp file="myfilename" match="^myList=(.*)" byline="true" replace="...
```

Note that you will need `byline="true"` otherwise the whole file will be treated as one string to process.

Comment: If i used ^ symbol also it is making change of the commented line only. 
//myList="a","b","c","d","e";
myList="a","b","c","d","e";
I have given parameter to add value after "e" in uncommented myList. But it append the new value in commented myList.

Comment: Hi Dinesh.  It may not help much but, "it works for me".  I added a note about line-by-line processing that may help.  Another thing I suggest is that perhaps your file was not "reset" to have the initial comment line in it before you reran; i.e. the comment was matched and processed in a run of Ant *before* you added the ^ to the build file.

Comment: Hi Martin, there was some naming convention issue earlier and so it did not work for me. Since I have modified it, its working for me. Thanks :)